# -Restcomm with Maria DB...but Administrator login fails

Tags: restcomm

We have installed RESTCOMM on UBUNTU and then changed the default password for administrator@company.com.
But later we have configured RESTCOMM with MARIA DB by following the steps https://docs.telestax.com/restcomm-install-and-configure-restcomm-to-use-mariadb/

Finally we restarted RESTCOMM.
But now when we try to login using administrator@compnay.com and with our  changed passowrd.  It is not going through.
But we thought that may be the Administrator password got reset to default as w have changed the DB from default hqlDB to Maria DB. So we tried to login with default "RestComm" but that is not working either.

Can i request you to pls. help us out if we are missing any thing ? How can we login as Administrator again?

thanks in advance
Ias

Answer (score 1):

You can manually reset the password.

First check the "restcomm_accounts" table for the record of the user "administrator@company.com". The "status" field should be "active".

Then you can update the record to change the "auth_token" field to "77f8c12cc7b8f8423e5c38b035249166" which is the default "RestComm" password.

Comment: Thanks George.  But the actual problem seems to be connectivity with Maria DB.

Answer (score 0):

We followed this article (https://docs.telestax.com/restcomm-install-and-configure-restcomm-to-use-mariadb/) to configure RESTCOMM to work with MariaDB, but we were facing some JBOSS AS level issues as the it is not able to properly locate and connect to the MariaDB Data source.
But we referred to com.h2database.h2 and compared with relevant config file  of HSQL DB that comes with Restcomm .  Based on our comparison, we had to make following tweaks to make it work. So, I would like to share here as It may be useful to the forum.

**1.** In step-3,   as per the article it should be as follows..
`<resource-root path="<strong>mariadb-java-client-1.2.0.jar</strong>`

Here we have removed the`<strong>`from the  path attribute.  So it is like this

```
<resource-root path="mariadb-java-client-1.2.0.jar"/>
```

Also we added `<module name="javax.servlet.api" optional="true"/>` as an additional module in dependencies element. So it is like this…

```
<dependencies>
  <module name="javax.api"/>
  <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
  <module name="javax.servlet.api" optional="true
```

**2**   In step-4, we have used the command  **mysql -u root -pyourpassoword < init.sql** instead of **mysql -u root < init.sql**

Also when we executed this init.sql we got the below error 
"ERROR 1406 (22001) at line 298: Data too long for column 'friendly_name' at row 1".
So to fix this error we have hanged the column friendly_name VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL to friendly_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL in restcomm_incoming_phone_numbers  table

**3**   In Step-5, in restcomm.xml, 
We have changed the existing xml element **from** `<strong><sql-files>${restcomm:home}/WEB-INF/scripts/mariadb/sql</sql-files></strong>`
**To** `<sql-files>${restcomm:home}/WEB-INF/scripts/mariadb/sql</sql-files>`

So, after the above 3 changes we are able to successfully connect MariaDB and get it up and running.
Hope the above changes are legitimate and most importantly I hope our above listed changes will not have any impact on RESTCOMM